# Firing a HTML attribute using angularjs without using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a HTML & javascript custom made attribute that will show a popup containing message when a button is clicked.

Button to click :

`<a data-deploy-menu="menu-sheet-tutorial-1" href="#">Tap Here to open</a>`

The sheet/popup that opens :

```
<div id="menu-sheet-tutorial-1" class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <h4>Hello, I'm action sheet!</h4>           
        <a href="#" class="close-menu button">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The **data-deploy-menu="menu-sheet-tutorial-1"** is what firing the event to open the sheet.

And, this is what happens when the button is clicked in javascript.

```
$('a[data-deploy-menu]').on( "click", function(){
        var menu_ident = $(this).data('deploy-menu');
        $('#'+menu_ident).addClass('active-menu');
        $('.fade-bg').addClass('active-fade'));
    });
```

And, this is what happens when the close button is clicked

```
$('.close-menu').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu-wrapper').removeClass('active-menu'));
        $('.fade-bg').removeClass('active-fade'));
    });
```

---

The problem i'm facing is that I'm not able to fire this event without a button click.
So, using angularJS, I want to fire this sheet automatically when the form is submitted or when a particular condition is true.

Comment: Why are you doing this with jQuery and not using `ng-click` and `ng-class`?

Comment: what have you tried so far to achieve fir the event? You can always listen to a event and trigger a function call , Or trigger your function on "mouse over", "hover" or on  the form submission success.

Comment: So far I have tried using `ng-class`. But the real problem is I can add dynamic class to the `.menu-wrapper` function based on condition. But as you see there is another div which is outside my controller scope that also needs to be modified (`.fade-bg`). So I'm not able to modify both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has a directive calls ngSubmit who could be provided with an expression like a function. Here is te documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit